# Lookup in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset that contains repeated observations on an individual in a long format. So each row as a type `A` or `B` observation. The following code reproduces the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1487)
dat <- data.table(id = rep(seq(10), 2), 
                  type = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)), 
                  x = sample.int(100,20))
dat
#     id type  x
#  1:  1    A 38
#  2:  2    A 58
#  3:  3    A 28
#  4:  4    A 21
#  5:  5    A 19
#  6:  6    A 62
#  7:  7    A 52
#  8:  8    A 86
#  9:  9    A 85
# 10: 10    A 90
# 11:  1    B 15
# 12:  2    B 11
# 13:  3    B 37
# 14:  4    B 93
# 15:  5    B 34
# 16:  6    B 91
# 17:  7    B 79
# 18:  8    B 94
# 19:  9    B 24
# 20: 10    B 41
```

Then I select out the top 3 individuals ranked by `x` for both types of observations:

```
setorderv(dat, c("type", "x"), c(1, -1))
top3 <- dat[, head(.SD, 3), by = list(type)]
top3
#    type id  x
# 1:    A 10 90
# 2:    A  8 86
# 3:    A  9 85
# 4:    B  8 94
# 5:    B  4 93
# 6:    B  6 91
```

Now I want to add a column that contains the original `x` value for the opposite observation type. If that makes any sense. So, the following code reproduces what I am looking for:

```
top3[,x2 := c(41, 94, 24, 86, 21, 62)]
#    type id  x x2
# 1:    A 10 90 41
# 2:    A  8 86 94
# 3:    A  9 85 24
# 4:    B  8 94 86
# 5:    B  4 93 21
# 6:    B  6 91 62
```

Of course I can go through the whole dataset row-by-row and use an `if` statement or whatever. The original dataset is quite big and I am looking for an elegant and efficient way to do it. I really like `data.table` and I have been using it a lot lately. I know there is a simple elegant way to do it. I also tried things using `.GRP`. I need some help.

Thanks in advance!

**MY FINAL SOLUTION**

Thanks to those who provided with inspiration. Those interested this is my working solution to my problem that actually works better for the intent of the project.

```
dat <- dcast.data.table(dat, id~type, value.var = "x")
top3 <- rbind(dat[order(-A), head(.SD, 3L)][,rank_by := "A"],
              dat[order(-B), head(.SD, 3L)][,rank_by := "B"])
#    id  A  B rank_by
# 1: 10 90 41       A
# 2:  8 86 94       A
# 3:  9 85 24       A
# 4:  8 86 94       B
# 5:  4 21 93       B
# 6:  6 62 91       B
```

Cheers,

tstev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want to merge back by `id` and opposite type. Depending on your particular circumstances I might just skip changing the type, and merge on both types, and discard the same one (code below assumes version `1.9.5+`):

```
(dat[order(-x), head(.SD, 3), by = type]
    [dat, on = 'id', nomatch = 0][type != i.type]
    [order(type, -id)])
#   type id  x i.type i.x
#1:    A 10 90      B  41
#2:    A  8 86      B  94
#3:    A  9 85      B  24
#4:    B  8 94      A  86
#5:    B  4 93      A  21
#6:    B  6 91      A  62
```

Comment: I would add new lines before each closing bracket `]` for readability

Comment: @jangorecki I experimented with a variety of ways I could separate this into at least 2 lines, but they all looked ugly to me, so I gave up. If you feel strongly about it - feel free to edit.

Comment: what you think about my edit? btw. it is the automatic formatting when using RStudio

Comment: thanks, it's ok; a large part of me is still unsatisfied, but it's not smth I'm going to lose sleep over :) What I'd really want to work, despite knowing that it can't, is to have newlines *in-between* the closing and the opening brackets.

Comment: Nice solution! But reading your discussion about readability I've thout on `dplyr` package. See update on my answer

Comment: @AndriyT. the readability discussion here is mostly due to SO's horizontal limitation. I personally find that `dplyr` readability is orders of magnitude worse no matter where you put the new lines.

Comment: @eddi, In my poor expirience I've found `dplyr` very useful. For example, in your solution It is not so clear (at least for me) what happens inside each bracket, instead dplyr provides an intuitive functions so it is more understandable each step from input to output

Comment: @jangorecki check out the edit - I'm experimenting with formatting, and I think I like this better - seems more readable, and is separated into logical pieces (at the cost of extra parentheses)

Comment: @AndriyT. "intuitive" is the assertion starting from which we disagree.

Comment: @eddi looks good but wrapping all into `(` - which I believe is required when `...[]\newline[]...` - adds new constraints which maybe confusing. For shorter chains I often use `[i,\newline j,\newline by]` style.

Comment: @eddi, thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately on my work laptop I have very little priviledges, so i cant install v1.9.5. However, i took your suggestion and adapted it! It worked! Cheers ~tstev

Comment: @tstev if little privileges are related to compiling package be aware you can do it on other machine and install package from compiled binary on your desired machine.

Comment: @jangorecki, sure enough, but I am not that experience with such things yet. Thanks a lot though! I got a working solution based on the answers and seeing as the project is almost done anyway - not sure its worthwhile pursuing this :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the most elegant way but it works:

```
setkeyv(dat, c("type", "id"))

my.order <- dat[order(-rank(type)), .(id, type)]
dat[, x2 := dat[.(my.order$type, my.order$id), x]]

setorderv(dat, c("type", "x"), c(1, -1))
top3 <- dat[, head(.SD, 3), by = .(type)]
top3

# type id  x x2
# 1:    A 10 90 41
# 2:    A  8 86 94
# 3:    A  9 85 24
# 4:    B  8 94 86
# 5:    B  4 93 21
# 6:    B  6 91 62
```

**EDIT**
Looking at @eddi's answer and the discussion about readability, I've remembered about `dplyr` package. So following his steps:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  arrange(desc(x)) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(head(., 3))) %>%
  left_join(., dat, by = "id") %>%
  filter(type.x != type.y) %>%
  arrange(type.x, desc(id))
#   id type.x x.x type.y x.y
# 1 10      A  90      B  41
# 2  9      A  85      B  24
# 3  8      A  86      B  94
# 4  8      B  94      A  86
# 5  6      B  91      A  62
# 6  4      B  93      A  21
```

Comment: there are 2 inconvinients in this code: add the new column to whole data instead of a resulting (smallest) so you get more data then you need; another is double `[` of data.table when creating a new column

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
subset(merge(top3, dat, by = "id"), type.x != type.y)[, type.y:=NULL][]   
#   id type.x x.x x.y
#1:  4      B  93  21
#2:  6      B  91  62
#3:  8      A  86  94
#4:  8      B  94  86
#5:  9      A  85  24
#6: 10      A  90  41
```

(To keep the same names as in your post you will need to wrap it in `setnames(..., c("id", "type", "x", "x2"))`)

Comment: great solution too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way. However, I suggest the following code:

```
## Merge separately for each type (drop type)
top3A <- merge(top3[top3$type =="A",2:3],dat[dat$type=="B",c(1,3)],by = c("id"))
top3B <- merge(top3[top3$type =="B",2:3],dat[dat$type=="A",c(1,3)],by = c("id"))
## add type which we dropped before
top3A$type <- "A"
top3B$type <- "B"
## combine both result sets
top3 <- rbind(top3A,top3B)
## rename columns and reorder/resort results
colnames(top3)[2:3] <- c("x","x2")
top3 <- top3[order(type,-id),c(4,1,2,3)]
```

Kind regards